# What is the proper way to pass a module as an argument?

Tags: module, rust, arguments

I have a module file (`src/map/map.rs`):

```
type Layer = Vec<Vec<Tile>>;

pub struct Map {
    height: i32,
    width: i32,
    data: Layer,
    rooms: Vec<Rect>,
}

impl Map {
    pub fn new(width: i32, height: i32) -> Self {
        Map {
            height: height,
            width: width,
            data: vec![vec![Tile::wall(); height as usize]; width as usize],
            rooms: vec![Rect],
        }
    }
    pub fn generate_with(&self, creator: module) {
        creator::generate(&self)
    }
}
```

a nested module `map::gen::dungeon::basic` (`src/map/gen/dungeon/basic.rs`)
with one function in the file:

```
pub fn generate(map: &mut Map) -> (Map, (i32, i32)) {}
```

and the `map` module file (`src/map/mod.rs`):

```
mod rect;
mod tile;
mod map;
pub mod room;
pub mod gen;

pub use self::map::Map;
pub use self::rect::Rect;
pub use self::tile::Tile;
```

imported into main.rs like this:

```
mod map;

use map::*;
use map::gen;
```

I want to be able to use it like this:

```
let (map, (player_x, player_y)) = Map::new(MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT).generate_with(gen::dungeon::basic);
```

the error I get though is:

```
[cargo] expected value, found module 'gen::dungeon::basic': not a value [E]
```

A complete [repo is available](https://github.com/Thermatix/cyber_rogue).

Comment: Modules are not values, but functions are. You should take the function as an argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in the comments, a module is not a concrete concept like that; what you are attempting to do is not possible.

Instead, you can pass something that can be a value:

```
mod basic {
    pub fn generate() -> u8 {
        0
    }
}

mod advanced {
    pub fn generate() -> u8 {
        42
    }
}

fn play_the_game(generator: fn() -> u8) {
    let dungeon = generator();
    println!("{}", dungeon);
}

fn main() {
    play_the_game(basic::generate);
    play_the_game(advanced::generate);
}
```

You could also introduce a trait and pass the implementing type as a generic:

```
trait DungeonGenerator {
    fn generate() -> u8;
}

mod basic {
    use DungeonGenerator;

    pub struct Basic;

    impl DungeonGenerator for Basic {
        fn generate() -> u8 {
            0
        }
    }
}

mod advanced {
    use DungeonGenerator;

    pub struct Advanced;

    impl DungeonGenerator for Advanced {
        fn generate() -> u8 {
            42
        }
    }
}

fn play_the_game<G>()
where
    G: DungeonGenerator,
{
    let dungeon = G::generate();
    println!("{}", dungeon);
}

fn main() {
    play_the_game::<basic::Basic>();
    play_the_game::<advanced::Advanced>();
}
```

Comment: I decided to go with the second one as I felt it better fit the API.